# Google Maps Infobox - markers behind current infobox trigger a new infobox on mouseover. And close infobox on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I've been playing around with this for a couple of hours now and I don't feel like I'm getting anywhere.

**Issue #1:** When I scroll over a map marker, it's infobox will show. However, when I run my mouse over the infobox and there is a different marker behind the shown infobox, the behind marker's infobox will open. I updated my infobox.js file and set this `enableEventPropagation: true`. But no luck.

**Issue #2:** When I mouseout of the map marker and infobox, I want the infobox to close. You can see in my commented out code below, I attempted to figure it out, but wasn't able. Anything I tried would cause the map to not load. How would I go about this?

Many thanks!

```
    events: {

            click: function(marker, event, context){
                    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

                    infobox.setContent(context.data);
                    infobox.open(map,marker);
            },
            mouseover: function(marker, event, context){

                    //map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

                    infobox.setContent(context.data);
                    infobox.open(map,marker);

            }
            // mouseout: function(marker, event, context){

                //  //map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

                //  // infobox.setContent(context.data);
                //  infobox.close(map,marker);

            // }                    
            }
        },          

        },"autofit");


    map = mapDiv.gmap3("get");
    infobox = new InfoBox({
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-165, -225),
        closeBoxURL: '',
        enableEventPropagation: true
    });
```

Comment: Please create a demo of the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.